# Conversion from Roman to decimal numbers

Tags: java, beginner, roman-numerals

My program makes a conversion between Roman and decimal numbers. Can you give me some advice on how to make it look more readable or to improve in general?

Would code extraction of similar-looking logic from `switch` cases into helper methods do the job? Or can we take some other approach and use recursion, enums or regular expressions to solve the conversion task?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Romans_to_Decimals 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    System.out.println("Enter roman number from I to MMMCMXCIX (1 to 3999), q to quit: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean done = false;
    while (!done && in.hasNext())
    {   
        String number = in.next();
        if (number.equals("q"))
        {
            done = true;
        }
        else
        {
            int result = 0;
            char[] array = number.toCharArray();

            for (int i = number.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                switch (array[i])
                {
                case 'I': 
                        result += 1;   
                        break;
                case 'X': 
                        if (i != 0 && array[i-1] == 'I')    //IX = 9
                        { 
                            result += 9;
                            i--;
                        } 
                        else
                        {
                            result += 10;
                        }
                        break;
                case 'C': 
                        if (i != 0 && array[i-1] == 'X')    //XC = 90
                        { 
                            result += 90;
                            i--;
                        } 
                        else
                        {
                            result += 100;
                        }
                        break;
                case 'M': 
                        if (i != 0 && array[i-1] == 'C')    //CM = 900
                        { 
                            result += 900;
                            i--;
                        } 
                        else
                        {
                            result += 1000;
                        }
                        break;
                case 'V': 
                        if (i != 0 && array[i-1] == 'I')    //IV = 4 
                        { 
                            result += 4;
                            i--;
                        } 
                        else
                        {
                            result += 5;
                        }
                        break;
                case 'L':
                        if (i != 0 && array[i-1] == 'X')    //XL = 40 
                        { 
                            result += 40;
                            i--;
                        } 
                        else
                        {
                            result += 50;
                        }
                        break;
                case 'D': 
                        if (i != 0 && array[i-1] == 'C')    //CD = 400
                        { 
                            result += 400;
                            i--;
                        } 
                        else
                        {
                            result += 500;
                        }
                        break;  
                default:
                        System.out.println("Not correct roman number");
                        break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Corresponding decimal number is: " + result);
            }
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> public class Romans_to_Decimals
> ```

*"when in Rome, do as the Romans do!"*
keep to Java naming conventions when programming java.

> ```
> for (int i = number.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
> ```

use the *fore each* notation if possible. In your case this would require a different approach to the problem tough...

> ```
> switch (array[i])
>  //..
>     if (i != 0 && array[i-1] == 'I')
> ```

use variables with explicit names.

> ```
>  case 'X': 
>                     if (i != 0 && array[i-1] == 'I')    //IX = 9
>                     { 
>                         result += 9;
>                         i--;
>                     } 
>                     else
>                     {
>                         result += 10;
>                     }
>                     break;
>             case 'C': 
>                     if (i != 0 && array[i-1] == 'X')    //XC = 90
>                     { 
>                         result += 90;
>                         i--;
>                     } 
>                     else
>                     {
>                         result += 100;
>                     }
>                     break;
>  for (char currentDigit:  number.toCharArray())
> ```

identify the variable elements whithing this code duplication and make them actula variables, then extract the logic to a method the getst the variables as parameters. Uning an enum to represent individual roman digits helps a lot:

```
    public class RomanNumbers {
        enum DigitValue {
            DIGIT_INVALID('-', 0),
            DIGIT_I('I', 1),
            DIGIT_V('V', 5),
            DIGIT_X('X', 10),
            DIGIT_L('L', 50),
            DIGIT_C('C', 100),
            DIGIT_D('D', 500),
            DIGIT_M('M', 1000),;
            private final char digit;
            private final int value;

            DigitValue(char digit, int value) {
                this.digit = digit;
                this.value = value;
            }

            static DigitValue getFor(char digit) {
                DigitValue[] values = values();
                for (DigitValue digitValue : values) {
                    if (digitValue.digit == digit) {
                        return digitValue;
                    }
                }
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(digit
                        + " is not valid part of a roman number");
            }

        }

        // member variable neede because we cannot return more than one value
        private static int result;  // static because you refused to create an actual object.

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Enter roman number from I to MMMCMXCIX (1 to 3999), q to quit: ");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            boolean done = false;
            while (!done
                    && in.hasNext()) {
                String number = in.next();
                if (number.equals("q")) {
                    done = true;
                } else {
                    result = 0;
                    char[] array = number.toCharArray();

                    for (int i = number.length()
                            - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        DigitValue currentDigit = DigitValue.getFor(array[i]);
                        DigitValue digitBefore = i > 0 ? DigitValue.getFor(array[i- 1]) : DigitValue.INVALID);

                        switch (currentDigit) {
                            case DIGIT_I:
                                result += 1;
                                break;
                            case DIGIT_X:
                                i = caculateFor(currentDigit, digitBefore, DigitValue.DIGIT_I, i);
                                break;
                            case DIGIT_C:
                                i = caculateFor(currentDigit, digitBefore, DigitValue.DIGIT_X, i);
                                break;
                            case DIGIT_M:
                                i = caculateFor(currentDigit, digitBefore, DigitValue.DIGIT_C, i);
                                break;
                            case DIGIT_V:
                                i = caculateFor(currentDigit, digitBefore, DigitValue.DIGIT_I, i);
                                break;
                            case DIGIT_L:
                                i = caculateFor(currentDigit, digitBefore, DigitValue.DIGIT_X, i);
                                break;
                            case DIGIT_D:
                                i = caculateFor(currentDigit, digitBefore, DigitValue.DIGIT_C, i);
                                break;
                            default:
                                System.out.println("Not correct roman number");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Corresponding decimal number is: "
                            + result);
                }
            }
            in.close();
        }

        private static int caculateFor(DigitValue currentDigitValue,
                DigitValue digitBefore,
                DigitValue reducingprevousDigit,
                int loopIndex) {
            result += currentDigitValue.value;
            if (digitBefore == reducingprevousDigit) {
                result -= reducingprevousDigit.value;
                loopIndex--;
            }
            return loopIndex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments, but I get an exception from getFor method, when I try to run your program.

Comment: what exception do you get?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Comment: and the nect line in the stacktrace? is it thown in `getFor()`

Comment: is not valid part of a roman number
 at RomanNumbers$DigitValue.getFor(RomanNumbers.java:34)
 at RomanNumbers.main(RomanNumbers.java:74)

Comment: looks like you pass a space in..., thy to replace  `'-'` with `' '` (a blank) in the first enum constant

Comment: strange, it works for XC or IX, but breaks for X

Comment: made the replacement, didn't help

Comment: the problem is here: `DigitValue digitBefore = DigitValue.getFor(i > 0 ? array[i- 1] : 0);` change to `DigitValue digitBefore = i > 0 ? DigitValue.getFor(array[i- 1] ): DigitValue.INVALID;`

Comment: interested in an even shorter version?

Comment: that would have been great

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47470/discussion-between-timothy-truckle-and-alex).

Answer (score 0):

This version expands the use of the `enum` and avoids the switch entirely:

```
    public class RomanNumbers {
        enum DigitValue {
            DIGIT_INVALID('-', 0),
            DIGIT_I('I', 1),
            DIGIT_V('V', 5),
            DIGIT_X('X', 10),
            DIGIT_L('L', 50),
            DIGIT_C('C', 100),
            DIGIT_D('D', 500),
            DIGIT_M('M', 1000),;

            private final char digit;
            private final int value;

            DigitValue(char digit, int value) {
                this.digit = digit;
                this.value = value;
            }

            static DigitValue getFor(char digit) {
                DigitValue[] values = values();
                for (DigitValue digitValue : values) {
                    if (digitValue.digit == digit) {
                        return digitValue;
                    }
                }
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(digit
                        + " is not valid part of a roman number");
            }

            public int calculate(int result, DigitValue prevoiusDigitValue) {
                // TODO: detect invalid combinations like 'VX'
                if (prevoiusDigitValue.value > value) {
                    result -= value;
                } else {
                    result += value;
                }
                return result;
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Enter roman number from I to MMMCMXCIX (1 to 3999), q to quit: ");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            boolean done = false;
            while (!done
                    && in.hasNext()) {
                String number = in.next();
                if (number.equals("q")) {
                    done = true;
                } else {
                    List<DigitValue> numberDigits = convertInput(number);
                    int result = calculateResult(numberDigits);
                    System.out.println("Corresponding decimal number is: "
                            + result);
                }
            }
            in.close();
        }

        private static int calculateResult(List<DigitValue> numberDigits) {
            int result = 0;
            DigitValue prevoiusDigitValue = DigitValue.DIGIT_INVALID;
            for (DigitValue digitValue : numberDigits) {
                result = digitValue.calculate(result, prevoiusDigitValue);
                prevoiusDigitValue = digitValue;
            }
            return result;
        }

        private static List<DigitValue> convertInput(String number) {
            List<DigitValue> numberDigits = new ArrayList<>();
            char[] array = number.toCharArray();
            for (char digitChar : array) {
                numberDigits.add(0, DigitValue.getFor(digitChar)); // reverses digits
            }
            return numberDigits;
        }
    }
```

Comment: any questions to this version?

Comment: Thanks! Have no questions yet, have to look at it carefully at first